# configurable product show 0 price

Tags: configurable-product

I'm new in configurable products.

when i try to change product material attribute in front end it shows me 0 price

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/USnNb.png]

i use wp_simple_products_generator to generate simple products

here is my data and configuration

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdWAx.png]

the attribute استیل is 20 units more expensive than default price(70.00)

thank you :)

EDIT:
it show correctly in the cart!
is it bug?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan i didn't write any code.